# DOM access to browser autosuggest for inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, browser, google-chrome

There is a way to access to the list of suggestions that the browser has stored? we can see when we focus on a textinput with the same name as an another form previous complete?

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe you can, for security reasons I think.

Comment: If you can, you should report it as a bug to the Chrome team lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible - to my knowledge, in no browser, not even in a "intranet" or "local" context. It would be a massive security problem if you could.